# Why is there a sometimes a trailing underscore in the Pipeline @Library() syntax

Tags: jenkins, groovy, syntax, jenkins-pipeline

Why does the `@Library()` call require the trailing `_` (underscore) character at least in some cases? e.g. `@Library('foobar-library@foobranch') _`

That seems completely superfluous to me but maybe there's a good explanation?.

Comment: `_` is a valid identifier in Groovy. The `_` is only required if you have no `import` statements. I am pretty confident it has to do with how Groovy compilation works and restrictions on annotations but I don't know the specifics enough to provide an answer.

Comment: This is so stupid. (yes, I'm semi-frustrated)

Answer (score 35):

Based on [this Jenkins blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/06/27/speaker-blog-SAS-jenkins-world/)

> After configuring Jenkins so that it can find the shared library repository, we can load the shared library into our pipeline using the @Library('') annotation.
>
> Since Annotations are designed to annotate something that follows them, we need to either include a specific import statement, or, if we want to include everything, we can use an **underscore character as a placeholder**.